# Use Jquery to make list options dependent on combobox

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

Im working on an ASP MVC application that uses twitter bootstrap. One of the views has two comboboxes, one of the comboboxes actually being an autocomplete combobox.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ObjectType, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ObjectType, new SelectList(Model.ObjectTypes.Select(x => new { Value = x, Text = x }), "Value", "Text"))
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Object</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" list="ObjectFieldOptions" id="ObjectField">
        <datalist id="ObjectFieldOptions">
            @if (true)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.ObjectList)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Item2" type="@item.Item1"></option>
                }
            }
        </datalist>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to make the options in the autocompletebox dependent on the selection made in the first combobox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#ObjectType").change(function () {
            var val1 = $("#ObjectType").val();
            $("#ObjectFieldOptions option").hide();
            $("#ObjectFieldOptions option[type=val1)]").show();


        });
    });
</script>
```

This is one of the options that i have been trying, without success. Is there an easy way to get this done?